# Why might toggles not work?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

[This page](http://wowballoons.com/wb/#) has toggles, in the "Why We're So Good" section. They suddenly stopped working. I don't know what might of changed since then. [This](http://themeforest.unitedthemes.com/wpversions/nevada/1/?color_scheme=F55D2D) is how they'd work, normally.

Could someone please explain how the toggles work in general, and why they aren't working now?

(Also, is there any way to find out what JavaScript is changing the document?)

EDIT: prettyPhoto is an a completely unrelated script that does lightbox stuff

Comment: Did you even check your error console? You're including a JS file that is not where you say it is. Cleanup all your errors, then get back to us...

Comment: You have included the script `    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
            
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
            
               
         
   /* Prettyphoto
   ================================================== */
   $("a[data-rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
    show_title: false
   });    
   
                 
        }); 
        
    })(jQuery);
 </script>
` before the script files are added, move it to the end of the file

Comment: I've tried executing that script in Firebug console after page has loaded but $(...).prettyPhoto still does not exist. Maybe you should remove that or add the prettyPhoto defenition

Comment: "what JavaScript is changing the document?" If you mean content then look for .html(something). If it's style then .css/.hide/.show/.toggle I'm sure I've missed some but that should get you most of the functions.

Comment: @Charlie, Arun, HMR: See edit, prettyPhoto exclusively does lightbox stuff. I'm not sure why wordpress is still putting the include there, but I didn't think it was that cruical.

Comment: @HMR: I mean, is it possible to find out which call from which script is responsible for some change

Comment: It isn't that straightforward I use firebug plugin in Firefox but you can use Chrome without plugin as well. Press F12, right click an element and "inspect element with firebug". Here you can see the class name or id. If it's an id then jquery usually gets the element with $("#theId") so you can go to the script tab and look for #theId if it doesn't have an id but a class then go to script tab and look for .theClass Your page needs prettyphoto and calls using prettyphoto can only be called after the prettyphoto js file has been loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `http://wowballoons.com/wb/wp-content/themes/nevada/nevada/javascripts/jquery.prettyPhoto.js?ver=1.3` file in your application, that is why it is not working.

Please download the [prettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/documentation/) script file and add it to your page.

Answer (score 0):

You have a script error on the html page:

```
$("a[data-rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
```

TypeError: $(...).prettyPhoto is not a function